# Avoiding the blank in files

Tags: c, pointers, file-io, counting, file-pointer

I'm writing a C code trying to avoid a blanks in a File. I just want to count one on every occurrence of the concatenated blanks.
For instance, if I have something like this:
`This is             just     a       test`
Whit any blanks like `'\n'`, `' '` or `\t` between that words. I've tried this:

```
if( (current_c == ' ') || (current_c == '\t') || (current_c == '\n') ){
            blank_counter++;
            do{
                fgetpos(file, &position);
            } while( (fgetc(archivo) == ' ') || (fgetc(archivo) == '\t') || (fgetc(archivo) == '\n') );
            fsetpos(file, &position);
            \***********************************************
            *******This is just debugging block*************
            printf("The current char: %c\n", current_c);
            fputc(c, file);
            ************************************************\
        }
```

Like you can notice, the above function is just a part. At the beginning I have the first instruction:
`while( (current_c = fgetc(file)) != EOF )`
And to work with `fsetpos()` and `fgetpos()` a declarative `fpos_t position;`.
I've a little troubles. If you run the code you could get a mistake. When the occurrence is `'\n'`, the pointer doesn't recognizes it.
Is there anyone how could help me with that?

Comment: It would help if you provided an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Your notation starting `\************************************` is not a comment; you've used a backslash instead of a (forward) slash `/`.  That means the code doesn't compile, which means it is hard to know what you're up to.  However, using `fgetpos()` and `fsetpos()` seems completely unnecessary.  You can most certainly deal with it using `just `fgetc()` and perhaps `ungetc()` — though using `ungetc()` needn't be necessary.  You should probably be using `isspace()` or `isblank()` from `<ctype.h>` header too.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to count the number of sequences of one or more blank, tab, or newline characters, then the code is basically trivial:

```
FILE *archivo = …
int c;
int blank_counter = 0;
while ((c = getc(archivo)) != EOF)
{
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
    {
        blank_counter++;
        while ((c = getc(archivo)) != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n')
            ;
    }
}
```

When you encounter a blank, tab or newline, increment the counter, then read as many more blanks, tabs or newlines as are available.  In this context, it doesn't matter that the inner loop reads some other character; that simply marks the end of the blank sequence and the outer loop resumes until the next white space is read.